# Loading Bootstrap with AMD Modules and typescript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm trying to load Bootstrap using RequireJS and typescript AMD modules.

At present I have the following in my requireJS config:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        bootstrap: { deps: ["jquery"] }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: "//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min",
        bootstrap: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min",
        d3: "//d3js.org/d3.v3.min"
    }
});
```

Then in a class I wish to do:

```
import jq = require("jquery");
import bootStrap = require("bootstrap");

class test {
    public doStuff(): void {
        jq("#test").carousel();
    }
}
```

Which is compiled by typescript into:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery"], function (require, exports, jq) {
    var testViewModel = (function () {
        function testViewModel() {
        }
        testViewModel.prototype.doStuff = function () {

            jq("#test").carousel();
        };
        return testViewModel;
    })();
})
```

So the problem seems to be because bootstrap extends jquery and is not actually used directly it's not output into the compiled javascript.

I can just include a reference to bootstrap somewhere in my class to fix the issue but this feels somewhat error prone.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would suggest using the `deps: ['bootstrap']` configuration ([ref](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps)). Resoning: Bootstrap is a framework, ambient to the entire application. It makes sense to load it at a top-most level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `import bootStrap = require("bootstrap");` will not generate any js unless you use the imported name *as a variable*. This allows you to do `lazy loading` and `importing type only` as [documented here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/external-modules.html).

## Fix :

```
import jq = require("jquery");
import bootStrap = require("bootstrap");
let bs = bootStrap;
```

Even better move such code into `ui.ts` and then import that file everywhere e.g. [`ui.tsx`](https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb/blob/31288f5ca13c914fa7f86bb260dc9bcc61667a9f/src/app/ui.tsx).

Comment: Thanks. Neat suggestion with ui.ts

Comment: I also prevents a *massive import* at the top of every file ;)